# Good practice for wcf service operation result

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

What is the best practice for Wcf service, in case we need to send fail/success result?

For example:
We have Wcf service, behind service we have some `BussinesLogic`.
Our service have one operation contract:

`[OperationContract] 
 /*SomeResult*/ SendImages(Bitmap[] images);`

**Possible scenarios:**

1. Operation complete, all successful.
2. Bitmap arguments are incorrect (wrong size or number of bitmaps).
3. `BussinesLogic` is in "bad" state. Logic is in error state and we
   dont know when it will avalible for work again.

Should i make custom `fault`? In wich case? Should i use generic `fault`? Should i make `enum OperationResult`? Or maby in case of success any result is like overkill?
Number of possible scenarios will be constant.

Comment: Either way you choose - the most important is to **be consistent**. I saw many times external systems that were sometimes returning error code, sometimes faults. And maybe at the beginning they even were able to understand why they choose one or another, after some time no one was able to justify this decision and we, as a client, always had to serve both ways.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I like to use this approach:

```
[DataContract]
public class OperationResult
{
  public OperationResult()
  {
    Errors = new List<OperationError>();
    Success = true;
  }

  [DataMember]
  public bool Success { get; set; }

  [DataMember]
  public IList<OperationError> Errors { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(Name = "OperationResultOf{0}")]
public class OperationResult<T> : OperationResult
{
  [DataMember]
  public T Result { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class OperationError
{
  [DataMember]
  public string ErrorCode { get; set; }

  [DataMember]
  public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}
```

Also I have some extensions:

```
  public static OperationResult WithError(this OperationResult operationResult, string errorCode,
                                          string error = null)
  {
    return operationResult.AddErrorImpl(errorCode, error);
  }

  public static OperationResult<T> WithError<T>(this OperationResult<T> operationResult, string errorCode,
                                                string error = null)
  {
    return (OperationResult<T>) operationResult.AddErrorImpl(errorCode, error);
  }

  private static OperationResult AddErrorImpl(this OperationResult operationResult, string errorCode,
                                              string error = null)
  {
    var operationError = new OperationError {Error = error ?? string.Empty, ErrorCode = errorCode};

    operationResult.Errors.Add(operationError);
    operationResult.Success = false;

    return operationResult;
  }

  public static OperationResult<T> WithResult<T>(this OperationResult<T> operationResult, T result)
  {
    operationResult.Result = result;
    return operationResult;
  }
```

The extensions make possible to return error with the one line of code:

```
return retValue.WithError(ErrorCodes.RequestError);
```

From my wcf service I never throw an exception.

Sorry for the wall of code

---

Caller's code is something like that. But it all depends on your requirements

```
OperationResult res = _service.Register(username, password);

if(!res.Success)
{
    if(res.Errors.Any(x => ErrorCodes.UsernameTaken)
    {
       // show error for taken username
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Do callers of your service actually process the list of errors? What do they do with the list?

Comment: I think you meant `res.Errors.Any(x=>x.ErrorCode == "UsernameTaken")` or something. That looks like a mess.

Comment: I would have upvoted such a comprehensive answer, but I think it's the _wrong_ answer. "Back in the day" we used to have to check return values from methods and service calls. Forgetting to check for errors, and the large amount of code dedicated to checking for errors, is why exceptions (and faults) were created.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, exceptions are expensive in wcf. Also I think that's no reason to throw exception, when for example username is taken. Moreover, how I can let user know that the request contains more than one error? For example, username is taken and password is too short

Comment: Don't think of it in terms of an exception. If you throw a `FaultException<T>`, then you are returning a SOAP Fault to the client.  `T` can be any data contract type, allowing you to return details to the client. The difference is that the client need not check for error status after each call, and in fact, does not need to handle errors on a call-by-call basis.